# Empty Html 5 Form Gets Submitted Without Showing Tooltips

Tags: php, html, forms

My html form has required inputs: Url, Anchor, Description.

Form labels are:

```
    $form_inputs_labels_array = 
    array("url"=>"required","anchor"=>"required","description"=>"required");
```

Each input field has following minlength & maxlength input requirements:

```
    $form_inputs_minlengths_array = array("url"=>"18","anchor"=>"2","description"=>"13");
    $form_inputs_maxlengths_array = array("url"=>"2048","anchor"=>"40","description"=>"255");
```

Form Properties are:

```
    $form_inputs_types_array = array("url"=>"url","anchor"=>"text","description"=>"text");
    $form_inputs_sizes_array = array("url"=>"25","anchor"=>"25","description"=>"25");
```

Issue is, when I make no inputs atall on any of the 3 input fields, then form gets submitted. Html 5 does not prompt for inputs to meet the min character input requirements.
However, if I do make inputs on any of the 3 fields without meeting the min requirement or if the input is invalid then I do get prompted by html 5 to fix my inputs.
I get prompts such as:

```
1. Please enter a url.
```

```
2. Please lengthen to 2 characters or more. (You are currently using 1 character).
```

But all these prompts appear only if I have made insufficient number of character inputs. These html alerts do not appear if I have made zero inputs or no inputs atall and submit the form.
I can write php code to check the inputs to meet requirements but that is taking the long route. Why is html 5 code failing here ?
And, why I get no tooltip popping up and why no text appear where I am supposed to hover my mouse to see the tooltips ?

**The Html Code**

```
    echo '
    <form method='POST' name='form' id='form' action=''>
    <fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <label for="url">Url:</label>
        <input type="url" name="url" id="url" minlength="18" maxlength="2048" size="25"'required'><div class='tooltipclass'><span class='tooltiptext'>
        <label for="anchor">Anchor:</label>
        <input type="text" name="anchor" id="anchor" minlength="2" maxlength="40" size="25"'required'><div class='tooltipclass'><span class='tooltiptext'>
        <label for="description">Description:</label>
        <input type="text" name="description" id="description" minlength="13" maxlength="255" size="25"'required'><div class='tooltipclass'><span class='tooltiptext'>
        
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <input type='reset'><br>
    <button type='submit' name='' id=''>Search!</button><br>
    </form>
    ';
```

**The Php Code**

```
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors','1');
    ini_set('display_startup_errors','1');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $form_types_array = array('register','login','signup','signin','submit','search');


if(ISSET($_GET['type']) && !EMPTY($_GET['type']))
{
    //WEBSITES->REGISTRATION/LOGIN FORM.
    if($_GET['type']=='register' OR $_GET['type']=='login')
    {
        $form_inputs_labels_array = array("domain"=>"required","email"=>"required","password"=>"required");
        $form_inputs_labels_count = count($form_inputs_labels_array);
        
        $form_inputs_minlengths_array = array("domain"=>"5","email"=>"7","password"=>"13");
        $form_inputs_maxlengths_array = array("domain"=>"255","email"=>"255","password"=>"128");
        
        $form_inputs_types_array = array("domain"=>"text","email"=>"email","password"=>"password");
        $form_inputs_sizes_array = array("domain"=>"25","email"=>"25","password"=>"25");
        
        if($_GET['type']=='register')
        {
            $button_label = 'Register';
        }
        if($_GET['type']=='login')
        {
            $button_label = 'Log-in';
        }
    }
    //USERS->SIGNUP/SIGNIN FORM.
    elseif($_GET['type']=='signup' OR $_GET['type']=='signin')
    {
        $form_inputs_labels_array = array("username"=>"required","email"=>"required","password"=>"required");
        $form_inputs_labels_count = count($form_inputs_labels_array);
        
        $form_inputs_minlengths_array = array("username"=>"8","email"=>"7","password"=>"13");
        $form_inputs_maxlengths_array = array("username"=>"40","email"=>"255","password"=>"128");
        
        $form_inputs_types_array = array("username"=>"text","email"=>"email","password"=>"password");
        $form_inputs_sizes_array = array("username"=>"25","email"=>"25","password"=>"25");
        
        if($_GET['type']=='signup')
        {
            $button_label = 'Sign-up';
        }
        if($_GET['type']=='signin')
        {
            $button_label = 'Sign-in';
        }
    }
    //WEBSITES->LINK SUBMISSION FORM.
    elseif(ISSET($_GET['type']) && !EMPTY($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type']=='submit')
    {
        $form_inputs_labels_array = array("url"=>"required","anchor"=>"required","description"=>"required");
        $form_inputs_labels_count = count($form_inputs_labels_array);
        
        $form_inputs_minlengths_array = array("url"=>"18","anchor"=>"2","description"=>"13");
        $form_inputs_maxlengths_array = array("url"=>"2048","anchor"=>"40","description"=>"255");
        
        $form_inputs_types_array = array("url"=>"url","anchor"=>"text","description"=>"text");
        $form_inputs_sizes_array = array("url"=>"25","anchor"=>"25","description"=>"25");
        
        $button_label = 'Submit';
    }
    //LABELS->SEARCHERS->SEARCH FORM.
    if(ISSET($_GET['type']) && !EMPTY($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type']=='search')
    {
        $form_inputs_labels_array = array("url"=>"required","anchor"=>"required","description"=>"required");
        $form_inputs_labels_count = count($form_inputs_labels_array);
        
        $form_inputs_minlengths_array = array("url"=>"18","anchor"=>"2","description"=>"13");
        $form_inputs_maxlengths_array = array("url"=>"2048","anchor"=>"40","description"=>"255");
        
        $form_inputs_types_array = array("url"=>"url","anchor"=>"text","description"=>"text");
        $form_inputs_sizes_array = array("url"=>"25","anchor"=>"25","description"=>"25");
        
        $button_label = 'Search';
    }
    else
    {
        die('Invalid Request!'); //Invalid Url. Invalid $_GET request.
    }
    
    $form_inputs_labels_array_keys = array_keys($form_inputs_labels_array);
    $form_inputs_labels_array_values = array_values($form_inputs_labels_array);
    
    $form_inputs_minlengths_array_keys = array_keys($form_inputs_minlengths_array);
    $form_inputs_minlengths_array_values = array_values($form_inputs_minlengths_array);
    
    $form_inputs_maxlengths_array_keys = array_keys($form_inputs_maxlengths_array);
    $form_inputs_maxlengths_array_values = array_values($form_inputs_maxlengths_array);
    
    $form_inputs_types_array_keys = array_keys($form_inputs_types_array);
    $form_inputs_types_array_values = array_values($form_inputs_types_array);
    
    $form_inputs_sizes_array_keys = array_keys($form_inputs_sizes_array);
    $form_inputs_sizes_array_values = array_values($form_inputs_sizes_array);
}

if(EMPTY($_GET['type']) OR !in_array($_GET['type'],$form_types_array))
{
    die('Invalid Request!'); //Invalid Url. Invalid $_GET request.
}
else
{
    echo 
    "
    <form method='POST' name='form' id='form' action=''>
    <fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    ";
    $lengths = "$form_inputs_minlengths_array_values[0],$form_inputs_maxlengths_array_values[0]";
    for($count=0;$count<$form_inputs_labels_count;$count++)
    {
        echo 
        "<label for=\"$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count]\">"; echo ucfirst("$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count]"); echo ':</label>
        <input type=' .'"' .$form_inputs_types_array_values[$count] .'"' .' name=' .'"' .$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count] .'"' .' id=' .'"' .$form_inputs_labels_array_keys[$count] .'"' .' minlength=' .'"' .$form_inputs_minlengths_array_values[$count] .'"' .' maxlength=' .'"' .$form_inputs_maxlengths_array_values[$count] .'"' .' size=' .'"' .'25' .'"'; if($form_inputs_labels_array_values[$count]=='required'){ echo "'required'>";} echo "<div class='tooltipclass'><span class='tooltiptext'>
        ";
    }
    echo 
    "
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    ";
    echo
    "
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <input type='reset'><br>
    <button type='submit' name='' id=''>$button_label!</button><br>
    </form>
    <br>
    ";
}
?>
```

**More about the php page.**
The page shows html form type based on $_GET['type'] parameter.
So, if the GET Param is register, then it will show a registration form.
And, if the GET Param is login, then it will show a login form.
And, if the GET Param is search, then it will show a search form.
And so on.

For our example, the above mentioned html form I showed you was based on the GET Param is search.

Thank You.

Comment: `required'` should be `required`. It's a property name not a value. Change that and see if it helps

Comment: @Adyson, Thanks! It worked. But, what about the ToolTip not working ?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what tooltips you're expecting or why. I see no code to add tooltips to anything. Have you got some JavaScript you're not showing?

Comment: @Adyson,Sorry! My mistake in the tooltipcode. Anyway, how do I accept your answer and close this thread ?